# Does each new Horcrux take half of Voldemort's remaining soul, thus taking a smaller piece each time?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux, souls

When you commit a murder and create a Horcrux, you split your soul. It’s been talked a lot about Voldemort splitting his soul in 7/8 parts. But I think his remaining soul was not 1/7 or 1/8 but far more weaker than that because he did not create all Horcruxes at once.

When he created his first Horcrux, his soul was split into 50-50 (diary). But when the second Horcrux was created, it was created by Voldemort only and the first Horcrux soul should have remained intact. Hence it would have been a 25-25 split of Voldemort's main soul. And so on for every split.

Am I right?

Comment: This is magic, not maths.

Comment: This depends on whether souls are a measurable quantity. Does it mean any more to say that you have half a soul than, say, half a sandwich? (Unless you have no soul, which is a different cup of tea altogether.)

Comment: Since JKR can't do maths, the answer to this question is meaningless at best.

Comment: Maybe, he can decide what amount of his soul can be transferred... So, maybe he knew that he would make 7 horcruxes, and he knew maths as well, he deliberately only transferred 1/7 of his soul each time... @Lohoris

Comment: @AwalGarg if the _author_ doesn't understand maths (or "setting consistency" for that matter), any point is moot. This universe doesn't work with logic. Actually, it doesn't work at all: you can just enjoy it suspending disbelief (and it is really good if you do), but don't try to make sense out of something, because there isn't.

Comment: Logically maths should be included, as how else first portion of the soul should know, exactly how many parts are going to be made. And here by portion it means strength in the soul left in him, to keep him alive.

Comment: Everything has measurable quantities, somehow.  Probably.  The question is whether you are able to quantitatively compare the strength of the soul shard in one horcrux to that of another, or are only able to discern a qualitative similarity.

Comment: I am very intrigued with this question- The Riddle who comes out of the Diary looks more "human"(with a normal nose) than the resurrected  bit of soul as Voldemort(negligible nose). Could this be a correlation of soul size? :P

Answer (score 29):

You're (probably) right that his remaining soul wasn't 1/8th of what he started with, but it also wouldn't have been 0.0078% of his total after being split that many times. There's simply no evidence that explicitly states it's a 50/50 split of the soul. The words most commonly used are "piece" and "fragment", and while they don't explicitly indicate a specific size, fragment by definition suggests that it's a portion of the soul much smaller than the whole.

> "Tell him that on the night Lord Voldemort tried to kill him, when Lily cast her own life between them as a shield, the Killing Curse rebounded upon Lord Voldemort, and **a fragment of Voldemort’s soul** was blasted apart from the whole, and latched itself onto the only living soul left in that collapsed building. Part of Lord Voldemort lives inside Harry, and it is that which gives him the power of speech with snakes, and a connection with Lord Voldemort’s mind that he has never understood. And while **that fragment of soul**, unmissed by Voldemort, remains attached to and protected by Harry, Lord Voldemort cannot die."
>   <sub>Chapter 24 - *The Prince's Tale*, Deathly Hallows</sub>

Six true Horcruxes (diary, ring, locket, cup, diadem, Nagini) created intentionally, then the fragment of soul that was inadvertently attached to Harry when Avada Kedavra backfired, means there would have been (at least) eight separate, but not equal sized, parts of Voldemort's soul.

Comment: Nail, meet Head. This answer is spot-on. A soul (in the Harry Potter universe) is an intangible, unquantifiable entity that we know very little about. It's speculative to try and apply mathematics and logic to the soul's mechanics. But overall, yes, Voldemort's soul is extremely damaged and irreparable.

Comment: I would like to add that Vampires have no reflection in a mirror because they don't have souls. I don't know if this is true in the Potterverse, but I wonder if Voldemort's reflection has been fading out since he started making horcruxes. (there is no indication of such in the memories collected by Dumbledore, but then a pensieve is a pensieve is a pensieve, not a mirror...)

Comment: Whether or not it takes half it's a lot more amusing to think of it that way. Tragic yes but amusing too.

Answer (score 9):

## There’s no indication that making a Horcrux splits the soul *in half*.

It’s unclear exactly how much of a soul the Dark Lord had left when he was done making Horcruxes (and accidentally left a piece in Harry). There’s nothing that states what percentage of the soul is split off to make a Horcrux - it’s just described as a piece or a portion.

> “Killing rips the soul apart. The wizard intent upon creating a Horcrux would use the damage to his advantage: he would encase the torn portion –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 23 (Horcruxes)*</sup></sub>

Since there’s nothing that states what fraction of the soul is split off to make a Horcrux, or what fraction is left, it’s not possible to deduce what fraction of his original soul the Dark Lord is left with.