# If horcruxes are destroyed what happens to the Maker?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

In the 7th movie part 2 (I suppose in the books also) Voldemort "killed" Harry which lead to destroying one of the Horcruxes that was inside Harry. Harry survived the killing curse and the battle continued with Voldemort dying.

Now let's say Voldemort had succeeded in killing Harry and that lead to ending the war and Voldemort prevailing. Now the remaining Horcrux is Voldemorts snake. 
Snakes have a finite lifespan.

Or let's say Neville killed Nagini after Harry's death and then Voldemort and the Death Eaters destroy everything and they prevail. The last Horcrux is also destroyed but there is no one to kill Voldemort.

Voldemort prevails but all the Horcruxes are destroyed. What would happen then? Would Voldemort age and die as well?

So basically, in many possible cases Voldemorts horcruxes could be destroyed while he won the war. What would happen then? He stayes alive and ages? Does he create new ones?(Does he have any soul left to do so?) or is he unkillable with time and only with magic?

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicate as the other question argues if a living thing is a suitable horcrux. What I am asking is what would happen if that said living thing dies out of age.

Comment: There's really two questions here: 1. Does being made a Horcrux make a living being immortal? This is more than likely a duplicate, at least I feel like we've covered this before. 2. What happens to Voldemort after his Horcruxes have all been killed? Easily answerable, may already have a question about it (I know the source material to answer this has already been quoted on other Horcrux questions).

Comment: What happens to a living being made Horcrux? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11627/3567 What heppens to Voldemort? "Harry: *"So if all of his Horcruxes are destroyed, Voldemort could be killed?"* Dumbledore: *"Yes, I think so. Without his Horcruxes, Voldemort will be a mortal man with a maimed and diminished soul."*" I assume that, being mortal, he would age and eventually die.

Comment: @alexwlchan Could he not create more horcruxes?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou: I can think of no reason why he couldn't. But his soul is so fractured and unstable that it might not be a good idea.

Comment: He would be able to easily create more, whether or not thats a good idea, who knows, but just making one makes your soul very unstables so the fact that he was at 7, without many noticable issues i assume he could at least make and 8th, if not another full 7 ( he may assume after a horrorcrux is destroyed that piece of his soul comes back to him) but needless to say , he most likely would have recreated at least 1 horrorcrux. also after his victory with nothing else to do, he could put his entire focus on creating a philospher stone,(its not unreasonable given 100s of years he could not dothis

Comment: Also relevant: [Why wouldn't Voldemort create new Horcruxes?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24215/3567)

Comment: It is explained in the books that to kill Voldemort, his horcruxes would have to be destroyed and he would once again be mortal. Mortals age and die of natural causes.

Comment: Voted to reopen, since the possible duplicate is about what happens to the maker of a horcrux _when they die_, while this question asks what (if anything) happens when their horcrux is destroyed. There is a throwaway comment in one of the answers that answers this, but that is unsourced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a lot of questions in one, but here is an overview of what I think you were asking.

Horcruxes work because they hold a little piece of their maker's soul. So Voldemort couldn't die (in the sense of moving on to the afterlife) because some of his soul was still earthbound.

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11627/are-living-beings-turned-into-horcruxes-suceptible-to-age-disease-or-injury) answers your comment about the horcruxes. If Nagini was the only one left when they won the war, she would eventually age and die.

> Voldemort prevails but all the Horcruxes are destroyed. What would happen then? Would Voldemort age and die as well?

Yes. There are no more pieces of his soul laying around, so he would be a normal human/wizard again.

> So basically, in many possible cases Voldemorts horcruxes could be destroyed while he won the war. What would happen then? He stayes alive and ages?

No. See above.

> Does he create new ones?(Does he have any soul left to do so?)

Probably not. [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24215/why-wouldnt-voldemort-create-new-horcruxes) answers that pretty well.

> or is he unkillable with time and only with magic?

See the first answer.